# How to use Customized Exception Handling Using Resource File in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, resource-files, custom-error-handling

I need to create a resource file for if any error occurs which should be goto resource file and show custom error message

If user want to change error message then he should change from resource file which should updated to custom error message created by programmer

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, all error messages will be stored in raw .resx files, then user can change the content of the file with any text editor, because these files are XML-formated.

You can retrieve a specified resource from the file programmatically: [Working with .resx Files Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that in this case, your resources should not be compiled to localized DLLs but stored as raw .resx files.